# Max file upload in bytes?

Tags: php

I'm using `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` to get the max file upload size.
The result is `5M`.

What is the easiest way to get this in bytes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the [return_bytes from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php):

```
function return_bytes($val) {
    if (empty($val)) {
        $val = 0;
    }
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    $val = floatval($val);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= (1024 * 1024 * 1024); //1073741824
            break;
        case 'm':
            $val *= (1024 * 1024); //1048576
            break;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
            break;
    }

    return $val;
}

return_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
```

Comment: huh.. I only get `Call to undefined function return_bytes() `

Comment: He is referring to the function that is stated in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough rep to comment on the solution by @fierycat

Just need to change `trim($string)` to `trim($val)`.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7 the solution will return: 'A non well formed numeric value encountered'

It might be used:

```
function return_bytes($val)
{
    preg_match('/(?<value>\d+)(?<option>.?)/i', trim($string), $matches);
    $inc = array(
        'g' => 1073741824, // (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
        'm' => 1048576, // (1024 * 1024)
        'k' => 1024
    );
    
    $value = (int) $matches['value'];
    $key = strtolower(trim($matches['option']));
    if (isset($inc[$key])) {
        $value *= $inc[$key];
    }

    return $value;
}

return_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
```